# phantomjs always giving parse error on windows

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

this might sound like a stupid issue but I can't seem to figure out at all why

I downloaded the windows binary and following the quickstart instructions and tried using the examples, but whatever and whenever I type anything in the console I always get "parse error"

I tried:

```
phantom hello.js

phantomjs hello.js
```

and some of the example scripts, and I always get 'parse error'

the hello.js file simply has this

`console.log('Hello, world!');`

`phantom.exit();`

I have no clue what's wrong...
any help would be appreciated...I'm sure this will turn out to be something stupid so I appreciate your time! thanks

Comment: See if `phantomjs --version` works at all.

Comment: no, also gives me parse error... phantom.exit() does work though

Comment: Then something is seriously wrong with your setup. `--version` should always just display the version information.

Comment: yes, exactly...thing is i just downloaded the binary as it is from the site, didnt compile it or anything...thought maybe i have to do somthing or i missed something .. ill try downloading again

Comment: still same problem...I tried this:
phantomjs> phantom --version
Parse error
phantomjs> phantomjs --version
Parse error


I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit...
I downloaded phantomjs-1.5.0-win32-static.zip, maybe it doesn't work on 64 bit?

Comment: There is your problem, the prompt from PhantomJS is for typing JavaScript code, not some 'phantom foobar'. When I wrote `phantomjs --version`, it is meant to be typed on the **Windows command prompt**, and not PhantomJS own REPL. Please read the documentation wiki for more details.

Comment: ah ok thanks, oddly enough I did not think of that..I think you should mention to run that from command prompt, the fact you can phantomjs itself might be misleading

Comment: It's already in the docs: "If PhantomJS is invoked without any argument, it will enter the interactive mode (REPL)."

Answer (score 8):

Add **'phantomjs-1.5.0-win32-static'** folder path to your system environment variable `path` and try `phantomjs --version` in new cmd prompt. If you can able to get the version correctly then you can execute your .js as below

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Your shoudnt run the **phantomjs.exe** file directly. you have to run it from **CMD**!